# Need start/stop script for Socket.io Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io

I developed an Instant Messaging application using Node.js/Socket.io
The application is deployed in Ubuntu. I can start the application from Ubuntu CLI as:
**`nodejs myserver.js`**
To stop the server, I need to press **CTRL+C** from the CLI. But if I closed the command prompt, next time onwards I don't have access for the Node.js/Socket.io server console. How can I start or stop the node.js/socket.io server from CLI may be as a service? I tried Forever also, but not succeed. 
Anyone can help me step by step. I am very new to Linux and Node.js

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a script file for start and stop the server by terminal

and you can use this command for access the console $ tail -50 filename
this will show you last 50 lines...

Comment: I am not sure what should be the content of the script file. Please elaborate.